# Can't manage to capture all the elements from a website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to extract all the odds from a betting website.
In order to do this, I need to find all the odds from every webpages [(i.e.)](https://paris-sportifs.pmu.fr/event/916212).
The problem I have is that is seems that some of the odds are "hidden" in the HTML and rendered by Javascript.

In this element:

When (class="table--main collapse") is set to "collapse", the odds are hidden. And when (class="table--main in") is set to "in", we can find the odds.

I tried using Puppeteer to scrape all the odds from the webpage, but I don't manage to find the ones that require interacting with the webpage.
Any idea of how to help me?

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://paris-sportifs.pmu.fr/event/915569');
  await page.waitForSelector('.table--main.in');
  const odds = await page.$$eval('.table--main.in .hierarchy-outcome-price', elements => elements.map(element => element.textContent));
  await browser.close();

  // Convert the array to a CSV string
  const csv = odds.join(';');

  // Write the CSV string to a file
  fs.writeFile('odds.csv', csv, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
  });
})();
```

Comment: What's your expected output, exactly? How many are you expecting to get?

Comment: My expected output is to have all the odds like this:
1N2/Elche/4,10
1N2/Nul/3,70
1N2/Seville/1,80
...

My problem is that when I request the page HTML, some odds are hidden.
I need to click on these elements in order to see all the odds:
"Vainqueur du match avec autre handicap.."
"1 2 Remboursé si égalité"
Etc.

Here is the link with the odds: https://paris-sportifs.pmu.fr/event/916215#table-content-45468731

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to show the data structure (you can omit after the first 3 or 4 entries), along with the exact count of all odds you expect? It's not clear to which elements we're clicking specifically.